# Level based acces control in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, access-control

I want to implement a level based access control in my ruby on rails application.
Like there a user at lower level will not be able to access data of its parent.
Example

```
  Main Admin
  |
  |___ Sub Admin1
  |      |
  |      |
  |      |___ SA1_USER1
  |      |
  |      |___ SA1_USER2
  |
  |
  |
  |___ Sub Admin2
         |
         |___ SA2_USER1
         |      |     
         |      |__End_user1
         |      |__End_user2
         |
         |___ SA2_USER2
```

In the structure above say every user can create a record. But records will be viewed according to the hierarchy. 
Like Main Admin will be able to access all records, Sub Admin1 can access records created by self, SA1_user1 and sa1_user2 and so on..

Is there any good plug in to implement this in ruby on rails?

Thanks,
PraWin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a plugin, but it wouldn't be all that hard to write yourself.  You would just have to have an owner_id on each created record you want people to access, and each user would have a parent user, then you would write up a model method for user.is_ancestor_of? record.owner to check anytime a user attempts to access a record.

Comment: Yes, I have this in my mind. Is there any method that will return all the ancestors for a node and also all children for a node.

Comment: nothing like that exists that I know of, you would likely have to write it from scratch.  hopefully someone else will have more info.

Comment: there is a nice plugin *ancestry*, which I used to implement this.

Comment: For hierarchy management there is a nice plugin ancestry https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry